# How to jump to exact point within a website?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, navigation, scrollbar

For example,

- [This screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MYNz.jpg) from:
  https://www.washingtonpost.com/graphics/world/border-barriers/global-illegal-immigration-prevention/
- And also [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYhGC.jpg) from:
  https://www.digitale-nomaden.ch/

I'm very new to coding and don't know what to google to find any tutorials on this, can anyone tell me what this type of "scrollbar" is called?

And how are these scrollbars made? Is it similar to a nav-bar just vertically and without text or is there a different method to achieve this?

Comment: You use `href="#element-id"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is called a [Fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Identifying_resources_on_the_Web#fragment) Anchor. It is used by specifying the element's ID preceded by a hash (`#`) as the hyperlinks href.

#### Step #1 - Add ID

For the element you'd like to scroll to, give it a unique [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) attribute

```
<div id="zutto-hachi"></div>
```

#### Step #2 - Create a link

Add the [`href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-href) to the link that you'd like to trigger the scroll action

```html
<a href="#zutto-hachi"></a>
```

#### Step #3 - Make it Smooth (optional)

Using CSS, you can animate this for a more natural effect, using the [`scroll-behavior`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior) property. For example:

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

---

#### Alternative

It's also possible to achieve the same thing with JavaScript.
For example:

```js
document.getElementById("zutto-hachi").scrollTo({ behavior: "smooth", top: 0 });
```

---

#### Example

Based on the examples in your screenshot, here's a quick demo:

```css
nav {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1rem;
  top: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 10rem;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background: #dcdcdc;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
nav a {
  font-family: monospace;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  width: 1rem;
  color: #fff;
}
.scroll-container {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.scroll-container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 12rem;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
.scroll-page {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 5em;
  color: #dcdcdc;
  font-family: monospace;
}


.scroll-page#page-1, nav a:nth-child(1) { background: #9b5de5; }
.scroll-page#page-2, nav a:nth-child(2) { background: #f15bb5; }
.scroll-page#page-3, nav a:nth-child(3) { background: #fee440; }
.scroll-page#page-4, nav a:nth-child(4) { background: #00bbf9; }
.scroll-page#page-5, nav a:nth-child(5) { background: #00f5d4; }
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#page-1">1</a>
  <a href="#page-2">2</a>
  <a href="#page-3">3</a>
  <a href="#page-4">4</a>
  <a href="#page-5">5</a>
</nav>
<div class="scroll-container">
  <div class="scroll-page" id="page-1">1</div>
  <div class="scroll-page" id="page-2">2</div>
  <div class="scroll-page" id="page-3">3</div>
  <div class="scroll-page" id="page-4">4</div>
  <div class="scroll-page" id="page-5">5</div>
</div>
```